# Trouble declaring and referencing global array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to create a global array in javascript to use in multiple functions. The array does not display when attempting to callback.

```
var iListCount = 0;
var arrListItems = new Array;

function addItem(){
    var list = document.getElementById('spanUser');
    var sText = document.getElementById('item-text').value;

    if (isNaN(iListCount)){
          iListCount = 0;
    }
    if (sText != "") {
        iListCount++;
        arrListItems[iListCount] = sText;
        list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML+"<li class='list-group-item' id='lis"+iListCount+"'>"+sText+"</li>";
        document.getElementById("item-text").value = "";        
    } else {
        document.getElementById("item-text").focus();   
        alert(arrListItems[1]);
    }
}
```

Edit: Html

```
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:65px" id="header-div">
              <label class="txt-sub pull-left">_items</label>
            </div>   
                <div style="margin-left:40px">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="item-text" style="margin-bottom:10px; width:200px;margin-right:10px" onKeyUp="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnAddItem').click()">
                        <button class="btn btn-default " onClick="addItem()" id="btnAddItem">add</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" onClick="removeItem()">remove last item</button>

                         <ul class="list-group" id="user-item" style="margin-top:10px">
                            <span id="spanUser">
                            </span>   
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--End Items-->
```

Comment: I would suggest that instead of using iListCount++ and a global counter, to just grab the arrListItems.length property when u need it, and instead of arrListItems[iListCount] = stext, use arrListItems.push(sText) to add new items on the tail end of the array

Comment: Can you post the html too?

Comment: When, where and how do you call `addItem`?

Comment: new Array should be new Array()

Comment: @Mike: If you don't pass arguments to the constructor, you can omit the parenthesis.

Comment: Can't get any better than this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20668853/144665 and this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2hEby/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global variables from the window object:

```
window.iListCount = 0;
window.arrListItems = [];
```

Are you only using `iListCount` as an index for `arrListItems` if so replace:

```
iListCount++;
arrListItems[iListCount] = sText;
```

with this:

```
arrListItems.push(sText);
```

And replace `iListCount` references with `arrListItems.length`.

I used the above suggestions in the following fiddle as well as some other good practice measures:

**http://fiddle.jshell.net/2hEby/**

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much. One final question: If I want to add an item to the list which has classes and styles etc, how do I?

Comment: Just change your HTML on this line: `list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML+"<li class='list-group-item' id='lis"+iListCount+"'>"+sText+"</li>";` - remember to up vote and accept. 
        `

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the array like that:

```
var arrListItems = [];
```

Comment: And why would that make a difference? `new Array` creates an array just as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the array result at the statement

`alert(arrListItems[1]);`

then make sure that the array has got two elements atleast.

First element of the array can be read using the index `0` and second with `1` and so on.

If you are trying to read first element, use

`alert(arrListItems[0]);`

Also the statements

```
iListCount++;
arrListItems[iListCount] = sText;
```

should be merged to one statement like this

```
arrListItems[iListCount++] = sText;
```

so that you can start adding elements to the array from it's first location.

You may also try

```
arrListItems[arrListItems.length] = sText;
```

**Example for `arrListItems[iListCount++] = sText;`**

[image]

Comment: arrListItems[iListCount++] = sText; doesn't work. It stops the adding of a list item to the dynamic list.

Comment: It will. Please check the posted image.

Comment: Using the `iListCount` to track array length is pretty hinky.

Comment: It should work in theory, the only problem is that when I run my code, an item is not added when I create a new list item.

Comment: The screenshot I took from **Google Chrome** console

Comment: You can check the site: www.trystanrivers.co